# Visual Studio 2015 CTP has no MVC option when targeting 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-templates

Using VS 2015 CTP, I'm trying to create a web application that targets fx 4.0
There is no MVC 4 Web Application template in the options.

That template does exist in VS 2013 Update 4.

Did I miss something in the install of VS 2015?

Comment: I suppose that Visual Studio 2015 will ship with the latest versions of the MVC template and that it won't ship with older versions of the MVC template. This has to do with support cycles in most cases. Products that ship with a certain technology, mean that said technology needs to be supported for x years. Why not create an MVC6 project, you're using Visual Studio 2015 right ;).